# MySQL Query with condition based on different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with measurements of stars. Each row (i.e. a measurement) contains the star's ID and its Period.

Lets say, for example:

```
Star_ID  Period
1        3.6
1        3.9
2        4.11
2        4.12
2        8.5
3        7.1
4        1.31
4        1.32
```

I want to write a query that returns the Star_ID's only of the stars which have measurements with "close" periods: stars which contain 2 periods which satisfies P1-P2 < x . In our example, for x = 0.02 it should return {2,4}.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thank a lot :)

Comment: So you start by writing a query, if it does not work ask for help with your query **SO !== free query coding**

Comment: Well apparantly I am wrong ___SO === Free queries coded here___

Comment: same star can't has the same period twice, correct ?

Comment: @Amr Magdy - correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is with a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t.star_id
from stars t join
     stars t2
     on t.star_id = t2.star_id and t.period <> t2.period
group by t.star_id
having min(abs(t.period - t2.period)) < 0.02;
```

Note:  This will ignore two duplicate rows (a difference of 0).